What are steps to develop and debug existing active workflows without interrupting current active workflows in repo?
We need to add new and modify existing and active GitHub Actions workflows of an existing repo. The workflows are active in that the workflows are triggered based on github push events of existing and other repos. How do we develop and debug to experiment and debug current workflows and not:

get triggered based on experimental branch because of push events of other monitored repositories; or

confuse or interfere with current active workflows?


Is there a wiki or blog that explains the process?
Local GHA tool 'act' doesn't seem to solve our problem.

If you want to test and debug your workflow without pushing unwanted code to the main branch, you can debug it directly on the repository. Here are a few options you can try:
Manual Trigger: Add on: workflow_dispatch to the workflow, and trigger it manually from your side branch.
on:
  workflow_dispatch:

Branch-Specific Trigger: Add on: push and specify your side branch instead of main. This way, every push to your branch will automatically trigger a workflow run.
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - <your_side_branch>

Pull Request Trigger: Add on: pull_request and open a PR to main. This will automatically trigger the workflow on every new commit to the PR.
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
    - main

Be aware that if you use workflow calls, you should update the tag so it uses the called workflow from your side branch, not the reference from main.

thx for responding, user15937765.

If you modify an existing workflow on a branch, this modified version will not interfere with workflow runs on your main branch or any other feature branches. It will only run on your branch when you push to your branch. Pushes to all other branches will use

the workflow from the main branch
the modified version of the workflow on those feature branches if they modified this workflow

Therefore, you can debug your modified workflow in isolation.
If you create a new workflow on a branch, you will not be able to run it until you merge it into the main branch. You will not be able to run it even on your branch.
In order for you to debug this new workflow, you will need to merge a minimal version of this workflow with the features you need (e.g. trigger types) to the main branch and then keep modifying it on a new branch - it becomes the existing workflow scenario.

thx for responding, Delta George. We'll digest what you said here. If you have concrete examples, that would be great too.

One point to be careful about. Push to a branch will trigger all workflows where push trigger branches pattern matches the name of the branch you pushed to. For example, if you have several workflows with a push to main trigger they will all run when you push to main.
